# Regex does not work on incoming mail

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, replaceall

I'm trying to delete gmail history before creating a case comment.

The line of code causing the problem seems to be

```
.replaceAll('On\\s.+\\sat\\s.+\\s<\\s*\\r*.+@.+>\\swrote:(.|\\n|\\r)*','')
```

The phrase I am searching for is

> On 25 April 2017 at 10:15, Donald Trump <
>     donald.trump@america.co.us> wrote:

The aim being to find this phrase, replace it and any subsequent
 characters with nothing, effectively deleting it. My regex works with
 editors on-line as straight java (i.e. with single \ rather than \\
 for Apex).

When I test in Sandbox or Production (by sending a mail from the case) it works fine.

When I test in Production (using email to case) the following error is returned

The following errors were encountered while processing an incoming email:

CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY : EmailMessageCopyToCaseComments: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 84857075-252026 (-423225879) (-423225879)

Class.EmailMessageCopyToCaseCommentsTrigger.copyEmailMessagesToCaseComments: line 15, column 1
Trigger.EmailMessageCopyToCaseComments: line 2, column 1

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger emailMessageCopyToCaseCommentsTrigger on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    emailMessageCopyToCaseComments.copyEmailMessagesToCaseComments(Trigger.new);
}
```

---

Here's the class:

```
public class emailMessageCopyToCaseComments
{
    public static void copyEmailMessagesToCaseComments(List<EmailMessage> emails)
    {
        List<CaseComment> comments = new List<CaseComment>();
        for (EmailMessage email:emails)
        {
            Id caseId = email.ParentId;
            CaseComment comment = new CaseComment(ParentId=caseId);
            String header = 'From: '+ email.FromName +'\n\n';

        if (email.TextBody!=null) {
            comment.CommentBody = header + email.TextBody.substringbefore ('This message and any attachment are only for the use of the intended recipient')
            .substringbefore ('-----Original Message-----')
            .substringbefore ('---------- Forwarded message ----------')
            .replaceAll('On\\s.+\\sat\\s.+\\s<\\s*\\r*.+@.+>\\swrote:(.|\\n|\\r)*','');

        } else if (email.HtmlBody!=null) {
            comment.CommentBody = header + email.HtmlBody.substringbefore ('This message and any attachment are only for the use of the intended recipient')
            .substringbefore ('-----Original Message-----')
            .substringbefore ('---------- Forwarded message ----------')
            .replaceAll('\\<.*?>','');    
        }

        comments.add(comment);
    }

    if (!comments.isEmpty())
    {
        insert comments;
    }
    }

}
```

I believe Marco Casalaina (Werewolf) is author of the original class and trigger which I have copied.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Christianluul. I haven't tried that with this particular error, but I shall and report back

Comment: Sorry I had not read your question correctly. When you get an error the code must run.

Comment: Do you have any validation rules on CaseComment in production that you do not have in the Sandbox? Sometimes when I see an error like this I create a new sandbox and deploy to that, then you should see the same error in the new sandbox.

Comment: Thanks again, Christianluul. I will check validation rules. I certainly have a lot of workflow on case comments and incoming mail.

Comment: I have also tested sending a mail from the case in Production and the regex works. The error still generates when email to case is used. The same would be true in Sandbox if I could test with email to case.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

I deleted an extraneous ( which I had in the line in production, but not sandbox and added a +, to make the last section

```
(.+|\\n|\\r)
```

so the final line which has tested OK is

```
.replaceAll('On\\s.+\\sat\\s.+\\s<\\s*\\r*.+@.+>\\swrote:(.+|\\n|\\r)*','')
```